# Dynamically show change iframe scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, html, iframe, scroll

I have one `IFrame`, i set `scrolling=no` for removing scroller from iframe. But in one case i need to show scroller for the same iframe dynamically. I can set scrolling attribute using attr method of jquery. But it does not make any change to iframe, once i reload the iframe by the code

```
$("#sample").attr('scrolling','yes')
document.getElementById("sample").contentDocument.location.reload();
```

then scroller will appear and working fine. But is any possible to dynamically show/hide ifrmae scroller without reloading the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this in Firefox 44.0.2 and its working fine the way you described without reloading the page.

It could be that your browser no longer supports the scrolling attribute as it is not part of HTML5. Instead you could try to use CSS and set the overflow to hidden on the iframe.

You should consider using both methods at the same time if cross browser compatibility does matter for your application.

Comment: yes its working in firefox alone, not working in chrome and IE

Comment: Did you try setting overflow to hidden as well ?

Comment: thanks a lot Lukas finally i achieved by setting overflow as hidden for body which is available inside iframe. t